# @State boolean value not changing when setting via a particular func within a SwiftUI struct

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, assignment-operator

I am trying to update a @State boolean named **showPopup** via a `showPopup(v: AnyView)` method which is located in my ContentView struct.

```
@State var popupShowing: Bool = false
```

The method `showPopup(v: AnyView)`, which sets the `popupShowing` boolean is also located in ContentView

```
public func showPopup(v: AnyView) {

    lightTap.impactOccurred()
    popupController.set(v)

    print("setting popupShowing to: true")
    popupShowing = true // this is what should be updating the @State boolean
    print("popupShowing = ", popupShowing)

}
```

The strange thing about this is, I have two methods which call showPopup and pass a reference of a `AnyView` and only one of them does not set the `popupShowing` boolean, the other method `tappedAddCT` works completely fine. (Both methods are also located in ContentView

Here is the faulty method with the call to `showPopup(v:Anyview)` that does not result in a change of the `popupShowing` variable

```
/*
 *  When editing a CT we bring up the popup add CT view with the corresponding elements
 */
public func showCTPopupFor(id: UUID) {
    let ct = cTypeHandler.getControllerFrom(id: id)!.ct

    // this is the call to the method above, for some reason it does not set the @State popupShowing boolean
    showPopup(v: AnyView(EditCubeTypeView(controller: ctEditController, contentView: self, setCT: ct)))

}
```

And here is the other method which calls `showPopup(v:Anyview)` that for some reason allows for `showPopup(v:Anyview)` to actually set the @State `showingPopup` boolean

```
public func tappedAddCT() {

    print("creating new Type view")
    showPopup(v: AnyView(NewCubeTypeView(controller: ctEditController, contentView: self)))

}
```

the call to `showPopup(...)` from the method above works for some reason.

Below are the console outputs, the output shows that, infact, the popupShowing variable is only being set via `showCTPopupFor(id:UUID)`

Here is also the outputs I am getting from the print statements in the `showPopup(v:Anyview)` method above

The unwanted result, which happens only when `showPopup(v:Anyview)` is called via `showCTPopupFor(id: UUID)`

```
setting popupShowing to: true
popupShowing =  false
```

The expected result, which happens only when `showPopup(v:Anyview)` is called via `tappedAddCT()`

```
creating new Type view
setting popupShowing to: true
popupShowing =  true
```

At first it seemed like a simple issue but I can't seem to figure it out, is there some @State SwiftUI rule I am completely overlooking or something?

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

After reorganizing my references I found that the reason the popupShowing variable was not updating was at some point, the main ContentView which the popupShowing variable was a child of was being destroyed and recreated by swiftui automatically in the background.
I guess swiftui does this with structs when it deems the struct old or unneeded.

I got around this by creating a separate ContentViewController class as a @StateObject of the ContentVIew.
The ContentViewController is a class rather than a struct so it stays constant through the run cycle.